# How to access 'this' context in Angular Class?

Tags: angular, class, this, undefined

Another 'context' problem.

I have this very function called '**isInDatabase()**'. It is supposed to be a custom validator, I got inspiration on 'angular/validator' Github page.

As you can see I'm calling the '**this.clientService.checkElement**' function. And as it is declared, I get the error: 'Cannot read property 'checkElement' of undefined'.

*Hint 1: (?)*

*According to what I have already seen and read, the context has changed, even if I use an arrow function, because this arrow function is wrapped in another function.*

*Hint 2: (?)*

*I have tried to implement this : `constructor (private clientService: ClientService) {}`, but then, the error was : error TS2339: Property 'clientService' does not exist on type 'typeof CustomValidators'.*

Here is the code :

```
export class CustomValidators {

    private static clientService: ClientService;

  static isInDatabase(elementType: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      this.clientService.checkElement(control.value, elementType)
        .subscribe(() => {
            return {isInDB: true};
          },
          (error) => {
            return {isInDB: true};
          });
      return (null);
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: So, if some people are interested: I have changed my static methods to non-static methods. That way, I need to instantiate an object of this class if I want to call my functions.

So it works, but at that point, I still need to know what is the best usage of static methods and why we do use static methods. (if someone has the answer btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `this` from a static method, because `this` references the instance of *this* class and you don't have an instance in a static method.

This article is also a nice read to better understand ['this' in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript).

Comment: Oooow! Seems logical! Even if I seem to definitey read this article... Thank you!